# Can you craft watches?

Tags: terraria-mobile

Can you craft watches in the mobile version of Terraria? Even with a lot of gold and chains, while at a table and chair, I still can't make one.

Comment: It should be craftable.  [Here's the wiki link](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Gold_Watch), and it doesn't say PC specific.  You may need to put up a screenshot, with your crafting/inventory open, to see what the issue is.

Comment: Actually right now watches gps phones and depth meters are all useless in mobile. They didn't write the functions in the script but keep them in chest incase they do add the functions.

Answer (score 2):

Are you at a TABLE and a chair, or are you next to a WORKBENCH and a chair? It's specific when it comes to that stuff. If your near a workbench and a chair then it won't work.

Comment: It's not possible to craft watches in the mobile version FWIW.

Answer (score 2):

No. It is not possible to craft watches in Terraria mobile version. I have the same problem. I hope they make it possible soon though.